# How to merge the elements in a list sequentially in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list `[ 'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd']`. How do I get the list which joins two letters sequentially i.e the ouptut should be `[  'ab', 'bc' , 'cd']` in python easily instead of manually looping and joining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip` within a list comprehension:

```
In [13]: ["".join(seq) for seq in zip(lst, lst[1:])]
Out[13]: ['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
```

Or since you just want to concatenate two character you can also use `add` operator, by using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) in order to apply the add function on character pairs:

```
In [14]: from itertools import starmap

In [15]: list(starmap(add, zip(lst, lst[1:])))
Out[15]: ['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
```

Comment: or better: `[x+y for x,y in zip(lst, lst[1:])]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just one line of code is enough :

```
a = ['a','b','c','d']
output = [a[i] + a[i+1] for i in xrange(len(a)) if i < len(a)-1]
print output
```